# Programmatically create and Add Owners and Members to O365 Group, no emails are sent

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sitepages, office-dev-pnp, modern-team-site

I'm using the code found in OfficeDevPnP.Core to create a new UnifiedGroup. UnifiedGroupsUtitlity.CreateUnifiedGroup. My code is below.

```
UnifiedGroupsUtility.CreateUnifiedGroup("CSOM Site Creation",
                                                            "My Site Created in Code,
                                                            CSOM,
                                                            accessToken,
                                                            groupLogo: null,
                                                            owners: owners.ToArray(),
                                                            members: members.ToArray(),
                                                            isPrivate: true,
                                                            createTeam: false);
```

When I'm using this code, none of the Owners or members get's an email saying they have joined the group, like they do if I add them manually to a group.

Do I have to write that part of the code to send the emails, or is there another method I can use that's already out there to send the same template that Microsoft sends?

There are two emails sent (if MS Teams included), when adding a person manually. One to say the person is added to the group from: The site on behalf of me.
One to say the person is added to the MS Teams. From: `noreply@email.teams.microsoft.com`

It these emails I wish to replicate when adding a user to Group/Team.

Comment: Interesting enough, I manually added myself to a group today and didn't get the email notification that I usually do. Maybe there's an issue with the backend process and not the PnP code..

Comment: Hi @Colbs, when I was writing the question above, I tested it manually and I got the emails. I needed to, to see what the from email address was.